# fading image over background image

Tags: html, css

Building a quick website. Ideally, I want it to look similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxEL6.jpg

Where, the hawaii background image is faded in at the start (and stays faded with an opacity of 0.2) & the rectangle in the middle fades in with the title and buttons but displays fully after the background image.

They'd be two seperate images (background #1 and rectangle #2) - how would I'd be best to do this with HTML/CSS? I have the background image working but the rectangle doesn't fade in and show. I'd like to have the buttons also link to pages (unsure how to do this)

Also having trouble finding the best way to resize my page to fit with the browser? I know it's alt tags but I can't remember the exact code needed.

I'm a noob and having trouble finding sufficient code to fulfil my request.

Cheers

CODE BELOW:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>index</title>
<link href="background.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <img src = "bkgd.jpg" alt=""/>

 <img src="backdrop.png" width="1920" height="1080" alt=""/> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
 @charset "UTF-8";
 /* CSS Document */

 html, body {

     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-size: auto;

 }

  img {
     opacity: 0.5;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
     background-attachment: fixed;


     /*Fade In Animation*/
     -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
          -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
          -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
          -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
             animation: fadein 2s;
 }

 @keyframes fadein {
     from { opacity: 0; }
     to   { opacity: 0.5; }
 }

 /* Firefox < 16 */
 @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.5; }
 }

 /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
 @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
     from { opacity: 0; }
     to   { opacity: 0.5; }
 }

 /* Internet Explorer */
 @-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 0.5; }
 }

 /* Opera < 12.1 */
 @-o-keyframes fadein {
     from { opacity: 0; }
     to   { opacity: 0.5; }
 }

 }
```

Comment: What have you tried? At least show code you have written and we can help if you have any issues

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @DierigPatrick Updated. Apologies.

Comment: Please correct URL to the images. Add your code into a fiddle ;)

Comment: @DierigPatrick not sure how to do this. Sorry :(

Comment: Visit: jsfiddle.net - write in the top left corner the html markup. On the right top corner you can add your css markup. The you can click on "Run" on the left top corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have added sample images. The first image is set as `body` background and the fading image is set as a `div` background.

To place the fading image in the middle of the page, use

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

To make the background image fit to screen width, use

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

```css
/* Body Margin*/

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Background Div*/

.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Background Div: after*/

.background:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  content: '';
  background-image: url("https://www.ncl.com/sites/default/files/DestinationGalleries.Hawaii.SnorkelingBay900x400.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat:  no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size:  cover;
  background-color: #999;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 10s;
  /*Fade In Animation*/
}


/* Fade in animations */

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

to {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Foregraound div */

.foreground {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*Fade In Animation*/
  -webkit-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 10s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 10s;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Name Tag */

.name-tag {
  font-family: 'avenir-light';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* Socail Media List*/

.social-media-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Socail Media Item*/

.social-media-link img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.social-media-link img:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.2);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<section class="background">
  <div class="foreground">
    <div class="name-tag">lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="social-media-list">
      <li class="social-media-link">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicolor-reading-writing/24/077_twitter-128.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="social-media-link">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-icons-the-circle-set/48/youtube_circle-128.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="social-media-link">
        <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-512.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="social-media-link">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-white-social-media/32/instagram_online_social_media-128.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd actually like the background inverted and the center image correctly displayed - as this will host buttons in the center? How would this be fixed? And is the code you provided all CSS?

Comment: To invert the image add this to the background image

    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);

Comment: Apologies. I mean, as in - I'd like the background image to fade, then stay at an opacity of 0.2, and the center image to fade in but have a opacity of 100% (visible). Just double checking, which parts of the code above are the CSS? Can you please make it clear which is HTML & CSS? Cheers

Comment: I've had a go at the code, and it doesn't seem to replicate a fade in effect on the background image. I've changed the center image to my own image and it doesn't show up? Bit unsure.

Comment: Wait let me have a look

Comment: Can I upload you my current .html & .css files somehow? Might make it a little easier.

Comment: Can you explain what que is?